# Nginx multiple locations each with its own root

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name ~^(?<cc>.+?).local.solar.bc.digital$;
  client_max_body_size 1m;

  root /home/vagrant/sites/$cc/_www/;
  index  index.html index.htm index.php;
  error_page 404 /index.php;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/$cc-access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/$cc-error.log;
  charset utf-8;
  sendfile off;

  location / {
    root /home/vagrant/sites/$cc/_www/php/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
  }

  location /shop/ {
    # root /home/vagrant/sites/$cc/_www/bcshop/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    fastcgi_param APP_ENV dev;
    fastcgi_param PLATFORM_ENVIRONMENT local;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
  }

  location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
  }
}
```

Right, given the config above. If you see what I am trying to do, know that it's not working!

Some details:

1. I have the general 'root', because without I get errors.
2. This is on a local VM used for development. We have a deployment tool locally that for each project (refer to $cc variable in the config above), it can deploy up to two apps. Not necessarily both are deployed for each project. The first app is deployed in `/home/vagrant/sites/$cc/_www/php`, the second one in `/home/vagrant/sites/$cc/_www/bcshop` (but I can make it `shop` - you'll see why from the config)
3. Both apps run on Drupal, so the way the load is the same. I simply can't make them work. I get file not found for both with most of the small variants I've tried.
4. When I place the second app in `/home/vagrant/sites/$cc/_www/shop` (rather than `/home/vagrant/sites/$cc/_www/bcshop`) I can get its homepage to load, but nothing else.
5. When I disregard the second app, and concentrate on the first, I can simply have a general root set to `/home/vagrant/sites/$cc/_www/php` and remove the local root from location `/`. That works. But it doesn't when it's specified as local root. In this case, in fact, I get this error in the logs: "FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream". This only for the first app.
6. If you wonder why the general root is set to that value, it's because I get an error in the logs if the general root is not verifiable for the location being matched. Makes sense?

I think I've covered pretty much all of what I've done in summary.

Thoughts?

I am not an expert at all with nginx, so I am going by trial and errors, with the help of the docs and other questions answered on here. But so far, no joy.

Thanks all.

Comment: Your *global* root is used by `location ~ \.php$` to resolve `$request_filename`. I still don't understand why you use `/home/vagrant/sites/$cc/_www` for PHP files and `/home/vagrant/sites/$cc/_www/php` for everything else.

Comment: @RichardSmith That's a good point. I suspected that myself, but I don't know how to get around my issue of having to have the general root not failing the test for existence (log error like: `testing "/home/vagrant/sites/shop/_www/php" existence failed`) when matching the second location (`/shop`).

I'd like `location ~ \.php$` to process the PHP for both the locations. Possible? The root for the `location ~ \.php$` should be `/home/vagrant/sites/$cc/_www/php` when it matches the first location and /home/vagrant/sites/$cc/_www/bcshop` when it matches the second. How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have PHP files in both the `_www/bcshop/` path and the `_www/php/` path. If you would like to use one common `location ~ \.php$` for both applications, then the URI for each application will need to be prefixed by `/bcshop` and `/php` respectively. That is, both applications *appear* to run in a subdirectory.

I suspect that you would like to use `/shop` prefix for one application, and the `/` prefix for the other. in which case two `location ~ \.php$` blocks will be required.

One application runs from the server root:

```
root /home/vagrant/sites/$cc/_www/php;
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri /index.php;

    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    ...
}
```

And one application runs with a URI prefix of `/shop` but located in the subdirectory `_www/bcshop`:

```
location ^~ /shop {
    rewrite ^/shop(?:/(.*))?$ /bcshop/$1 last;
}

location ^~ /bcshop/ {
    internal;
    root /home/vagrant/sites/$cc/_www;

    try_files $uri /shop/index.php?$query_string;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /shop/index.php;

        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        ...
    }
}
```

The `^~` modifier ensures that the `location` block takes precedence over the regular expression location block above. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

Although the external URI prefix is `/shop`, it is silently rewritten to `/bcshop` so that we can continue to use the `root` directive. There is an `alias` directive, but it has [issues with `try_files`](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97) and is tricky to use with PHP.

Comment: Great, thanks. Any reason why when hitting the `/shop/` app is now downloading the `index.php` file, rather than just process it?

Comment: The shop's PHP files are processed by the nested `location ~ \.php$` block (that is the one **inside** the `location ^~ /shop` block). That block needs to be virtually identical to the first `location ~ \.php$` block so that PHP files are passed to FastCGI for processing.

Comment: They are identical, except the `try_files` line. Mhm.

Comment: kind of hidden in the original question: what would I have to do if I wanted the `/shop` location to have its `index.php` located at `_www/bcshop`? Notice the difference `bcshop` instead of `shop` for the directory where the app is located.

Comment: Yeah, I ignored that requirement - but I have updated the answer with my preferred solution.

Comment: Thanks Richard, much appreciated. Learnt a lot today.

Comment: I've only tried that now. The rewrite works as long as you hit just `/shop`. Anything under there doesn't work. I mean, it does if I bypass the "nice urls" system of drupal, and just pass params to `index.php`. But things like `/shop/user` should work (Drupal will transform that to `/shop/index.php?q=user`). But I get file not found in that case, instead.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer by @RichardSmith, I come up with my own variant (which is working fine). Simply because repeating the block for `location ~ \.php$` was doing my head in.

```
...
...
root /home/vagrant/sites/$cc/_www/;
...
...
location / {
  set $actual_root /home/vagrant/sites/$cc/_www/php/;
  set $fastcgi_index /index.php;
  root $actual_root;
  try_files $uri $uri/ $fastcgi_index?$query_string;
}

location /shop/ {
  set $actual_root /home/vagrant/sites/$cc/_www/;
  set $fastcgi_index /shop/index.php;
  root $actual_root;
  try_files $uri $uri/ $fastcgi_index?$query_string;
 }

location ~ \.php$ {
  root $actual_root;
  fastcgi_index $fastcgi_index;
  fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
  include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $actual_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
  fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
  fastcgi_param APP_ENV dev;
  fastcgi_param PLATFORM_ENVIRONMENT local;
  fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
  fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
  fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;      
}

...
...
```